Why Isn't My Object Showing

I don't know why but it isn't showing the object, I hid it to make something else, but when I unhide it, it doesn't show up, why? Is there anyway to fix it?

You are in Local view (see info in the top left of your viewport), which limits the view to objects which are selected while switching to local view. I guess it wasn't the cube object which was selected in that moment. Toggling local view on/off is done by pressing Numpad /.Try and see if this brings back the objects. By the way, the tag under your question is misleading, this has nothing to do with rendering at all and even if so, Blender's internal render engine has been removed several years ago now.
